# Web api Action gets called twice from android/iOS app on server

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-4.5

I am facing a tricky issue. I have a web API project for Android & ios.
Whenever I deploy my code on the server, a particular Action gets called twice & gets executed twice when in reality from Android /iOs application it's been called only once.

This behaviour shows me an error that data already present. Which is because the first execution has already stored the data which the system is checking again for the second call & execution. We have check application side. The call is made once only.

I am using Visual studio 2012, .net framework 4.5.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("ActionName")]
    public HttpResponseMessage ActionName(object obj) 
    { 
       {




        if (obj.Key_Parameter != "" && obj.Key_Parameter != null)
        {
            App_Code.CheckApiKey check = new App_Code.CheckApiKey();
            bool result = check.CheckApi("Leave", "ApplyLeave", obj.Key_Parameter);
            if (result == false)
            {

                type = "Fail"; status = false; message = "Invalid Api Key,Please check!";
                HttpResponseMessage Invalid = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new { type, status, message });
                return Invalid;
            }
            else
            {
                obj.DateFrom = obj.DateFrom.Replace('-', '/');
                obj.DateTo = obj.DateTo.Replace('-', '/');
                DateTime DateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(obj.DateFrom, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                DateTime DateTo = DateTime.ParseExact(obj.DateTo, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                DateTime chkDate = DateTime.Today;
                if (obj.LeaveType == "PL" || obj.LeaveType == "CL" || obj.LeaveType == "SL")
                {
                    if (!Confirmed(Convert.ToInt64(obj.UserCode)))
                    {
                        type = "Fail"; status = false; message = "Can't Apply not confirmed";
                        HttpResponseMessage Invalid = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { type, status, message });
                        return Invalid;
                    }
                }
                if (obj.LeaveType == "ML")
                {
                    if (obj.Gender.Trim() == "")
                    {
                        type = "Fail"; status = false; message = "Can't apply for ML !!!";
                        HttpResponseMessage Invalid = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { type, status, message });
                        return Invalid;
                    }
                    if (obj.Gender.Trim() == "MALE")
                    {
                        type = "Fail"; status = false; message = "Only Females can apply for ML";
                        HttpResponseMessage Invalid = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { type, status, message });
                        return Invalid;
                    }
                    if (GetDaysAfterConfirmation(obj) < 161)
                    {
                        type = "Fail"; status = false; message = "Can not apply for ML now. Please read the Leave Policy for Maternity leave for futher details";
                        HttpResponseMessage Invalid = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { type, status, message });
                        return Invalid;
                    }
                }
                if (obj.LeaveType == "PL")
                {
                    if (GetDaysAfterConfirmation(obj) < 365)
                    {
                        type = "Fail"; status = false; message = "You can apply PL only after completion of 1 year";
                        HttpResponseMessage Invalid = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { type, status, message });
                        return Invalid;
                    }
                }
                if (obj.Allow.Trim() == "N")
                {
                    int nDays = (chkDate - DateFrom).Days;

                                 }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                if (dataadded == false)
                {


                    if (CheckDate(DateFrom, DateTo, obj.UserCode) == false)
                    {

                        string tempdate1 = obj.DateFrom;
                        string tempdate2 = obj.DateTo;
                        temp123 = 4;
                                         type = "Fail"; status = false; message = "Period specified is not correct or overlapping.";
                        flag = false;
                        HttpResponseMessage Invalid = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { type, status, message });

                        return Invalid;
                    }
                }
                if (obj.LeaveType.Trim() != "COMP" && obj.LeaveType.Trim() != "LWP" && obj.LeaveType.Trim() != "ML")
                {
                    if (HasBalance(obj) < Convert.ToDecimal(obj.Days))
                    {
                        type = "Fail"; status = false; message = "Not enough " + obj.LeaveType + " Balance ";
                        HttpResponseMessage Invalid = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { type, status, message });
                        return Invalid;
                    }
                }
                if (obj.Days > 0 && obj.Days < 1)//Wrong Condition
                {
                    if (DateFrom != DateTo)
                    {
                        type = "Fail"; status = false; message = "Invalid Period Specified";
                        HttpResponseMessage Invalid = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { type, status, message });
                        return Invalid;
                    }
                }

                if (Convert.ToDecimal(obj.Days) <= 0)
                {
                    type = "Fail"; status = false; message = " Number of days can't be zero ";
                    HttpResponseMessage Invalid = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { type, status, message });
                    return Invalid;
                }
                if (obj.LeaveType == "PL")//Wrong Condition
                {
                    if (obj.Days < 3)
                    {
                        type = "Fail"; status = false; message = "Minimum days for PL should be equal to or more than 3 days";
                        HttpResponseMessage Invalid = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { type, status, message });
                        return Invalid;
                    }
                }
                if (obj.LeaveType == "CL")
                {
                    if (obj.Days > 2)
                    {
                        type = "Fail"; status = false; message = "Casual leave can not be more than 2 days";
                        HttpResponseMessage Invalid = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { type, status, message });
                        return Invalid;
                    }
                }
                if (obj.LeaveType == "ML")
                {
                    if (obj.Days > 84)
                    {
                        type = "Fail"; status = false; message = "ML can be taken for 12 weeks only ";
                        HttpResponseMessage Invalid = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { type, status, message });
                        return Invalid;
                    }
                }

                if (temp123 != 1 && temp123 != 4 && flag)
                {
                    SqlConnection conz = new SqlConnection(conString);
                    try
                    {

                        string cmduz = "insert into z(datefrom,dateto,empcode,lremark,lyear,ldays,adddate,leavecode,status) values (@datefrom,@dateto,@empcode,@lremark,@lyear,@ldays,@adddate,@leavecode,@status) ";
                        SqlCommand cmda = new SqlCommand(cmduz, conz);
                        cmda.Parameters.Add("@datefrom", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = DateFrom;
                        cmda.Parameters.Add("@dateto", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = DateTo;//DateTo.SelectedDate;
                        cmda.Parameters.Add("EMPCODE", SqlDbType.Int).Value = obj.UserCode;
                        cmda.Parameters.Add("@LEAVECODE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = obj.LeaveType; //cmbLeaveType.SelectedValue;
                        cmda.Parameters.Add("@lremark", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = obj.Remarks;//txtRemarks.Text;
                        cmda.Parameters.Add("@LYEAR", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DateFrom.Year;
                        cmda.Parameters.Add("@adddate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = System.DateTime.Now;
                        cmda.Parameters.Add("@ldays", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = obj.Days;//txtDays.Value;
                        cmda.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Unapproved";
                        cmda.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        obj.ActFlag = "";

                        conz.Open();
                        cmda.CommandText = cmduz;

                        cmda.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        dataadded = true;
                        cmduz = "";

                        type = "Success"; status = true; message = "Leave Added Successfully" + dataadded + ".";
                        HttpResponseMessage ok = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { type, status, message });
                        //return ok;


                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        type = "Exception";
                        status = false;
                        message = "Leave Added Successfully2";
                        HttpResponseMessage Excep = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed, new { type, status, message });
                        return Excep;
                    }

                    try
                    {

                        App_Code.FcmPushNotification notification = new App_Code.FcmPushNotification();
                        string Message = "Leave Request From " + obj.Name;
                        notification.SendPushNotification(obj.PushUserCode, Message, "Applied");

                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                    try
                    {
                        if (obj.Allow == "Y")
                        {

                            UpdateEmployeeMaster(Convert.ToInt64(obj.UserCode));
                            if (File.Exists(fileLoc))
                            {
                                string LogMsg = "Update Emplotee Master Function Executed.";
                                log(LogMsg);
                            }
                        }
                        string vmessage = " I would like to apply for " + obj.LeaveType + " From " + DateFrom.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + " to " + DateTo.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + " for " +/*txtDays.Text*/ obj.Days + " day(s). \n\n";

                        if (obj.Remarks.Trim() != "")
                        {
                            vmessage = vmessage + "\n\n Remarks: " + obj.Remarks;
                        }
                        vmessage = vmessage + "\n\n Kindly approve !!! at " + ApproveURL;

                        int vEmpCode = Convert.ToInt16(obj.Reporting);



                        string Mail_result = InformUser(vEmpCode, vmessage, "Leave Application Employee Code:" + obj.UserCode + " Name :" + obj.Name + " Date :" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), obj);


                        if (Mail_result == "Success")
                        {
                            type = "Success"; status = true; message = "E-mail Sent Successfully";
                            HttpResponseMessage ok = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { type, status, message });

                            return ok;
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            type = "Success"; status = true; message = "E-mail could not be sent";
                            HttpResponseMessage Excep = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { type, status, message });
                            return Excep;
                        }

                        //  InformUser(vEmpCode, vmessage, "Leave Application Employee Code:" + obj.UserCode + " Name :" + obj.Name + " Date :" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), obj);
                        // HttpResponseMessage ok = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success !!");
                        // return ok;

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        type = "Success";
                        status = true;
                        message = "Email could not be sent";
                        HttpResponseMessage Excep = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed, new { type, status, message });
                        return Excep;
                    }
                    finally
                    {

                        conz.Close();

                        conz.Dispose();


                    }
                }
            }
        }
        type = "Fail"; status = false; message = "fail";


        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { type, status, message });
    }
```

Comment: Please post the client side code as well as the relevant server side code. I have never seen such behaviour without some client call errors, or a explicit call fromm the server.

Comment: @Stefan this is the server side code , the application side call is fine.still i will find & post it here.

Comment: Hmm, that a lot of code XD. Where does the error rise? By the way: the action does not run twice by itself. So the problem *must* be either @ the client side or you are doing some magic stuff internally. I think you should test if the client actually post it's data once. And the best option is to test the API with a web-debugger like fiddler. http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: well , i am struggling through this from last two days & i have made a log file  & it clearly states that ApplyLeave is entered twice one after another.i will try your fiddler. let's see. Even the app side is calling it once omly. I am trying to use action filter as a flag so that it can only enter where it is one otherwise not , is it possible ?

Comment: Because it's a lot of code, it's quite hard to read. Nevertheless, if you want to make sure your code is runned 1 at the time, you could use a `lock` statement. Although this would be a bandaid. This won't prevent it from running twice, but it will ensure that it will be executed one at a time. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx Make sure your lockobject is marked `static` in your case.

Comment: Can you tell me how to kill the next thread along with current thread?

Comment: That's not a path to take. The problem is that the endpoint is called multiple times. These request will be handled on different threads. You could put a log in place at the entry point of ActionName endpoint. If it's logging twice, your endpoint is called twice. You'll need to find out why. Try to recreate the request with fiddler, if the endpoint is called once the problem lies at the client side, if not, perhaps a added authentication filter or action filter might be causing this.